# (Python3) Check if a variable is in an sqlite3 Database

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

im programming a Discord bot. It saves Usernames and theire money in a sqlite3 database.
Now i need to check if a Username is alredy in the Database to prevent double entries.

```
money4 = 1000


def add_player(user):
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO player VALUES (?,?)", (str(user), int(money4)))
    connection.commit()
```

thats the code to add the name into the database. With that people can get double entries and i just want to block that.
edit: Database looks like this with multiple entries:

```
[('message.author', 1000), ('Micheltv10#9087', 1000), ('bempel#2040', 1000), ('bempel#2040', 1000), ('Micheltv10#9087', 1000), ('Micheltv10#9087', 1000), ('Micheltv10#9087', 1000), ('Micheltv10#9087', 1000), ('Micheltv10#9087', 1000)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to select the username before inserting to check if it already exists. Or do it properly and make the username unique (maybe as the primary key) in your database structure, so inserting duplicates would throw an error.

Comment: and how can i do that? What functions can i use

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a table with a primary key.

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE spieler(
            spielername TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
            money INTEGER
            )""")
```